# "If" condition with multiple choices (RUBY)

Tags: ruby, if-statement

I'm a beginner at ruby and I can't seem to find a solution to this simple thing:

I have a variable I got by random: `var1 = rand (0...100)`

And I want that variable to be acceptable only if it's 25 or 75. If it's not, it keeps doing randomness until it gets either to 25 or 75.

```
var1 = rand(0...100)

until var1 == (25 or 75)
var1 = rand (0...100)
end
```

the variable "var1" ALWAYS gives out 25 because it sticks to 25 and doesn't accept 75.

The thing is: How can I make it so that an statement includes two options without one having prevalence? I've tried putting parentheses but it doesn't seem to work. Hope you can help!

Greetings.

Comment: write as `var1 == 25 || var1 == 75`..

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `Array` and [`include?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-include-3F):

```
until [ 25, 75 ].include? var1
```

Or a simple `or`:

```
until var1 == 25 or var1 == 75
```

Or simply generate a number between `0` and `1` and replace `0` with `25` and `1` with `75`.

Comment: I don't understand why to create an array for this..?

Comment: @ArupRakshit Depends, with a greater amount of possible values this makes it more readable. It also matches what the questioner tried more closely. I edited in a simple `or` anyway.

Comment: Tim, in this case it probably doesn't make much difference which way you do it.  If, however, you had `[a,b,...,z].include?` v`, where the elements were methods, `a`, `b`,...,`z` would all have to be evaluated in constructing the array, whereas `a` || `b` || ..` would terminate as soon as a method evaluated `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Just to explain a bit more :

In Ruby all object has truth value, except `nil` and `false` value. With this *rule of thumb*, `25` is a `Fixnum` object, which must be having *truth* value.

Now in your conditional expression - `var1 == (25 or 75)`, inside *parens*, `25` and `75` both are having *truth* value, on which you used `or` operator. As per the *or* expression, if **LHS** evaluated as `true`, **RHS** wouldn't be evaluated, thus `(25 or 75)` would return always `25`.

Thus to fix it write as below :

```
until var1 == 25 or var1 == 75
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast and detailed response - my code now works :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to choose either a 25 or 75, do this:

```
[25, 75].sample
```